# How do I inspect an element when a page has a custom context menu?

Tags: javascript, context-menu, right-click

I am trying to inspect elements on a file management script which I bought, the script uses custom context menu all over the site
thanks for any help.
PS: the page content is really huge so i can't just press F12 and find the element and then edit it.

Comment: The "search" feature of the inspect element console (`F12`) isn't sufficient enough?

Comment: nope, and i don't really know what i'm searching for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's as simple as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`Right Click`. It works for me in both Chrome and Firefox on YouTube.

[This is YouTube's custom overlay on a right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLhrY.png)

[This is Firefox's own right click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHhHa.png)

Comment: not what i'm looking for